# Java: counting number of times data appears in a class

Tags: java, class

I know how to count most things when it comes to Java, but this has either stumped me a lot, or my brain is dying. Anyway, I have a class called "Jobs", and within that class is a String variable called "day". Multiple new Jobs have been created already (exact number is unknown), and now I need to query and find out how many Jobs are on x day. I assume it would be easy enough with a while loop, but I don't know how to create one that looks through Jobs as a whole rather than one specific one.

The Job data was created by reading a file (the name of which is jobFile) via a Scanner.

```
public class Job_16997761 {

  private int jobID;             // unique job identification number
  private int customerID;        // unique customer identification number
  private String registration;   // registration number for vehicle for this job
  private String date;           // when the job is carried out by mechanic
  private String day;            // day of the week that job is booked for
  private double totalFee;       // total price for the Job
  private int[] serviceCode;     // the service codes to be carried out on the vehicle for the job

  //Constructor
  public Job_16997761(int jobID, int customerID, String registration, 
          String date, String day, double totalFee, int[] serviceCode) {
      this.jobID = jobID;
      this.customerID = customerID;
      this.registration = registration;
      this.date = date;
      this.day = day;
      this.totalFee = totalFee;
      this.serviceCode = serviceCode;
  }
```

Comment: Try posting some code such as your `Jobs` class. Also how are the `Jobs` created and where do they exist in the application (eg: who knows they exist)?

Comment: If you want accurate answers, I advise you to post some code.

Comment: Do you have something like a `List` where all `Job`s are referenced?

Comment: Added Job class in. They were created from a file (the program read the file and stored them as new Jobs)

Comment: So the `Job` are just created on the fly and not referenced in any sort of `Collections` ?

Comment: As per op, it seems all the job data is in a file which is then loaded into I assume a collection of class `JobData`.

Comment: The data all comes from the file and there isn't any Collection or something like JobData. It's just simple reading from file and putting into a class.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are creating a dynamic instance of a job (eg. Job_16997761, it seems that each job has its own class). But when creating the jobs you can maintain a map that will have the number of jobs per day. Something like:

```
Map<String, Long> jobsPerDay=new HashMap<String,Long>();
```

Then when creating a new job you can simply increment the counter for each day:

```
jobsPerDay.put(day,jobsPerDay.get(day)!=null?jobsPerDay.get(day)++:1);
```

This way you will be able to get the number of jobs for a day by using: `jobsPerDay.get(day)`

Please note that you can use `java.time.DayOfWeek` instead of a `String`.

Comment: Just a side note on this approach: when you use `jobsPerDay.get(day)` it will return `null` if you haven't put a job in for that day and the result will be a NPE. You should either put  a ternary operator or `if` test to deal with it.

Comment: @ug_ Yes, true if no job was added for a particular day.

Comment: The number is just my student number at uni, it was required to be on all the java files we submit.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of the many ways and may not be that efficient, but this is one way you may consider (Before you edited your last post). Using an arrayList to contain all the Job objects and iterate through the objects.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SomeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Jobs job1 = new Jobs(1);
        Jobs job2 = new Jobs(1);
        Jobs job3 = new Jobs(2);
        Jobs job4 = new Jobs(2);
        Jobs job5 = new Jobs(2);                                

        ArrayList<Jobs> jobList = new ArrayList<Jobs>();
        jobList.add(job1);
        jobList.add(job2);
        jobList.add(job3);
        jobList.add(job4);
        jobList.add(job5);

        System.out.println(numOfJobOnDayX(jobList, 2)); //Jobs which falls on day 2
    }

    public static int numOfJobOnDayX(ArrayList<Jobs> jobList, int specifiedDay)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int x=0; x<jobList.size(); x++) //May use a for-each loop instead
            if(jobList.get(x).days == specifiedDay)
                count ++;
        return count;                   
    }   
}
```

**OUTPUT:** `3`

Class for Jobs..

```
class Jobs
{
    int days;       
    public Jobs(int days)
    {
        this.days = days;
    }   
}
```

For simplicity, I am not using any getter and setter methods. You may want to think about what data structure you want to use to hold your objects. Once again, I need to re-emphasize this may not be an efficient way, but it gives you some ideas some possibilities of doing the count.

Comment: `String` can't be compared with `==` for equality. And also you seem to be comparing `Jobs` with `String`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell you correct solution unless you give more details. You are saying you can write `while` loop so I will assume you have a collection of `Job` already.

```
int count = 0;
List<Job> jobs = readJobsFromFile();
for(Job job : jobs) {
    if(job.getDay().equals(inputDay)){ //inputDay is day you have to find number of jobs on.
       count++;
    }
}

System.out.Println(count);
```